# Axios is adding a prefix to the api target url

Tags: flask, axios

I know this may be the dumpest question ever asked, however it really got me this hopeless :(

I have the React front End with a simple property in package.json 
`"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"`
which I believe is redirecting all api sent through axios to that servr address. 
My axios request is

> `const canvas_type="standard" 
>   axios.post('api/v1/new_canvas',{
>           canvas_type
>       })
>   }`

The backend flask api is:

> `@api_bp.route("/new_canvas", methods=["POST"])
>   @requires_auth
>   def get_new_cavas():
>   """working code"""`

The code works perfectly when tested with Postman,
but when I call the axios, I get this line in the server output

> 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2018 23:51:12] "POST /designer/api/v1/new_canvas HTTP/1.1" 405 -

Comment: What browser are u using? Can u provide the curl command that browser emulates using Developer Tools?

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)
As a first step, I am trying to make the api call by a simple button click, what is suspecious (please don't laugh), is that the component is wrapped in react-router Route
<Route path="/designer/:canvas_id" component={Designer} /> 
Designer happens to be the component where the api is called :/
maybe axios is getting things twisted ?
And somehow in the devtool, the api is sent to http://localhost:3000/designer/api/v1/new_canvas
instead of 
http://localhost:5000/api/v1/new_canvas

Comment: ... that's weird, I changed the route path and now it works -_-

Comment: Oki! how can I delete my stupid question ! xD it is just a leading forward slash "/" that is missing
axios.post('/api/v1/new_canvas' ....) just works perfectly